# How to fetch Working hours using google calendar API in ruby?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Unable to find information at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  edit your question include your code describe what you are trying to do and any issues you are having with your code.

Comment: A feature request [Expose Working Hours within API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112248486) was opened by someone on the Public Issue Tracker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment of this answer there is no available feature for retrieving the working hours throughout the API.

However, you could use the [Freebusy query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query) to retrieve the calendar hours you will be busy as a workaround for getting the working hours (you then can of course filter the response data to just get the working hours and not any other busy moment you are not interested in).

Moreover, if you would like to request this feature for Google Calendar API, you can file a feature request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906).

Comment: I just tested this and it's unfortunately not true. The Freebusy endpoint only returns busy for the "primary" calendar when there are actual events scheduled.